# build your application with ng build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I try to use ng build, but the error message says "Error: Unknown argument: prod" I used this command "ng build --prod --base-href=/website.github.io/" I tried to update everything I don't know what to do and what to change. I tried this in my angular application.

[! [This is the output of the command I called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNwqb.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNwqb.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--prod` argument has been removed in Angular 14 as it's the default for `build`.

If you want to specify environemnt, use `ng build --configuration production`